# Decrease font size of a QLineEdit gradually

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit

I want to use `QLineEdit` in Qt5 to do this:

When I use a function `f()` to set specific text in a `QLineEdit` object, I want it so that after a second, the font size of the text will automatically get smaller.

How do I do that?

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've tried -- preferably a [mcve].

Comment: I have tried to add a "for cycle",but fail.In that way,I can only see the smaller one.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#ifndef OWNTEXTEDIT_H
#define OWNTEXTEDIT_H

#include <qlineedit.h>
#include <qtimer.h>

#define STARTSIZE 30
#define SPEED 50
#define ENDSIZE 15

class OwnTextEdit : public QLineEdit {
    Q_OBJECT
          
public slots:
    void setText(const QString& text) {
        QLineEdit::setText(text);
        m_timer->start(SPEED);
        m_size = STARTSIZE;
        setFont(QFont(font_name, m_size));
    }

public:
    OwnTextEdit(QWidget *parent = 0) {
        setMinimumSize(QSize(500, 100));

        m_timer = new QTimer(this);
        QObject::connect(m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &OwnTextEdit::decreaseSize);
    };

    ~OwnTextEdit() {};

private slots:
    void decreaseSize() {
        if (m_size == ENDSIZE) m_timer->stop();

        m_size--;
        setFont(QFont(font_name, m_size));
    };

private:    
    QTimer* m_timer;
    unsigned int m_size = STARTSIZE;
    const char* font_name = "Arial";
};

#endif // OWNTEXTEDIT_H
```

I inherited QLineEdit, and my overridden method `setText` calls `QLineEdit::setText` and starts the timer, which decreases the font size from `STARTSIZE` to `ENDSIZE` gradually.

Comment: Thank you so much!I think your idea can perfectly solve my problem.I will try it when I am free.